# Determine intersection of plane with z-axis without using cross product

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the points $(2,-1,-2),\,(1,3,12),\,(4,2,3)$ which lie on a plane and I need to determine where the plane crosses the z-axis. This can easily be solved using cross product to determine the equation of the plane and plugging in $(0,0,z)$ but I need a way to solve it without using the cross product. Any ideas and suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $ax + by + cz = d$ will describe the desired plane 
if the values of $a,$ $b,$ $c,$ and $d$ are set appropriately.
The equation is still valid if you multiply all these parameters by a non-zero constant;
assuming the plane has a $z$-intercept, $c \neq 0,$ so you can multiply all parameters
by a suitable constant so that $c = 1.$ Now you have
$$ax + by + z = d.$$
Plug in the first given point, so $x = 2,$ $y = -1,$ and $z = -2:$
$$2a - by - 2 = d.$$
Now you have an equation with just three unknowns. 
Use the other two given points this way,
and you will have three equations with three unknowns.
Since the three points are not collinear, this system of three equations is solvable.

You don't actually need to solve the whole system of equations; you are looking for
the value of $z$ when $x = 0$ and $y = 0,$ which is given by $z = d.$

Alternative: the three points define three distinct non-parallel lines.
If the plane has a $z$-intercept, at least two of those lines must intersect the
$(x,z)$ plane. Find the two points of intersection. These define a line that
intersects the $z$-axis at the same point where the plane does.

Answer (score 0):

The vector equation of your plane is $\underrightarrow{r}={{\underrightarrow{r}}_{0}}+s({{\underrightarrow{r}}_{1}}-{{\underrightarrow{r}}_{0}})+t({{\underrightarrow{r}}_{2}}-{{\underrightarrow{r}}_{0}})$ where ${{\underrightarrow{r}}_{0}}$, ${{\underrightarrow{r}}_{1}}$ and ${{\underrightarrow{r}}_{2}}$ are your three points and s, t are two parameters. If this represents (0, 0, z) then equating the three components your first two will let you find s and t (2 simultaneous equations) and substituting for s and t in the third will give z.